# Change src atribute from img, using Simple HTML Dom php library

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm totally new to php, and I'm having a hard time changing the src attribute of img tags.
I have a website that pulls a part of a page using Simple Html Dom php, here is the code:

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.tabuademares.com/br/bahia/morro-de-sao-paulo');

foreach($html ->find('img') as $item) {
    $item->outertext = '';
    }

$html->save();

$elem = $html->find('table[id=tabla_mareas]', 0);
echo $elem;

?>
```

This code correctly returns the part of the page I want. But when I do this the img tags comes with the src of the original page: /assets/svg/icon_name.svg

What I want to do is change the original src so that it looks like this: http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/svg/icon_name.svg
I want to put the url of my site in front of assets / svg / icon_name.svg
I already tried some tutorials, but I could not make any work.

Could someone please kind of help a noob in php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

did you read the documentation [for read and modify attributes](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) 
As per that

```
// Get a attribute ( If the attribute is non-value attribute (eg. checked, selected...), it will returns true or false)
$value = $e->href;

// Set a attribute
$e->href = 'ursitename'.$value;
```

Comment: Hi @zod, i see that page. But I'm quite a noob on php language. Don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

i could make it work. So if someone have the same question, here is how i managed to get the code working.

```
<?php

// Note you must download the php files simple_html_dom.php from 
// this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

//than include them
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

//target the website
$html = file_get_html('http://the_target_website.com');

//loop thru all images of the html dom
foreach($html ->find('img') as $item) {

// Get a attribute ( If the attribute is non-value attribute (eg. checked, selected...), it will returns true or false)

        $value = $item->src;

        // Set a attribute

        $item->src = 'http://yourwebsite.com/'.$value;
    }
//save the variable
$html->save();

//findo on html the div you want to get the content
$elem = $html->find('div[id=container]', 0);

//output it using echo
echo $elem;

?>
```

That's it!