# How to correct image links in scraped html using regex

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Scraping using SimpleHTMLDom retrieves the HTML on the page as written but not as seen in the web browser and unless written to include the full url to their location on the website, they twill be missing information needed to display properly. Those links can be varied, some with no leading slash (/) and others using (../). So I have created a script to hopefully retrieve the (img src) using regex and then loop though each one, check if the domain name is included, and if not, inject it.

```
$homepage = "https://example.com/";
$html = '<img class="drt" src="100.png"><img src="../101.png"><img src="/102.png"><img src="103.png">';

$check_img = preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $html, $m); 

foreach ($m[1] as $img){    
    if (strpos($img, $homepage) == false) {
        if (strpos($img, '../') !== false) {
            $html = str_replace('../', $homepage, $img);
        } elseif ($img[0] == '/') {
            $html = str_replace('/', $homepage, $img);
        } else {
            $html = substr_replace($img, $homepage, 0, 0);
        }      
    }    
}
echo $html;
```

But it only injects the last image and for some reason the <> are missing from the html.

Comment: just use domdocument and get the src attribute, add the domain then replace it

Comment: Getting the src is not the problem. It is replace that is not working.

Comment: yeah because your matching images looping over them and then replacing $html, when you should be looping over only the images and changing just the src for that dom element. to fix you would need search and replace the $img from $html not the other way. https://3v4l.org/V2WDs messy though

Comment: np, answered with a couple of ways, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct) or other HTML parser (edit: you already are using SimpleHTMLDom but I'm unfamiliar with it, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201054/change-src-atribute-from-img-using-simple-html-dom-php-library) if you want to use it), it's better in the long run especially if you want to tweak or get other elements.

```
<?php
$homepage = "https://example.com/";
$html = '<img class="drt" src="100.png"><img src="../101.png"><img src="/102.png"><img src="103.png">';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
    if (strpos($img, '//') === false) {
        $src = $homepage.basename($src);
        $img->setAttribute('src', $src);
    }
}

// hacky way! remove unwanted doctype ect
$ret = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|body|head))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $dom->saveHTML());
echo trim(str_replace('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">', '', $ret));

// proper way! but you dont have correct DOM, no <body>
// remove <!DOCTYPE 
//$dom->removeChild($dom->doctype);           
// remove <html><body></body></html> 
//$dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);
//
//echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

https://3v4l.org/1sf3B

Or to produce the same result with your current code, but possibly prone to breaking use [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to remove the `./` and `../`, and possibly `../../`

```
<?php
$homepage = "https://example.com/";
$html = '<img class="drt" src="100.png"><img src="../101.png"><img src="/102.png"><img src="103.png">';

$check_img = preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $html, $m); 

foreach ($m[1] as $img){    
    if (strpos($img, '//') === false) 
        $html = str_replace($img, $homepage.basename($img), $html);    
}
echo $html;
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/LvL82

Or do the longer checks and replace the `$html` with the replaced `$src` value

```
<?php
$homepage = "https://example.com/";
$html = '<img class="drt" src="100.png"><img src="../101.png"><img src="/102.png"><img src="103.png">';

$check_img = preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $html, $m); 

foreach ($m[1] as $img){    
    if (strpos($img, '//') === false) {
        $old_img = $img;
        
        if (strpos($img, '../') !== false) {
            $img = str_replace('../', $homepage, $old_img);
        } elseif ($img[0] == '/') {
            $img = str_replace('/', $homepage, $old_img);
        } else {
            $img = $homepage.$old_img;
        }  
        
        $html = str_replace($old_img, $img, $html);
    }    
}
echo $html;
```

All produce the same result.

Comment: Found a bug in the #2 and #3... when an image appears on the page more than once, the script is injecting $homepage into them more than once

Comment: yeah as left out `strpos($img, $homepage) === false`, added it in now

Comment: That fixed #2 but not #3

Comment: Changed $homepage to // because links may use CDN. But now I have an error...strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string because of nominating // which needs to be escaped, but how?

Comment: thanks for the edit.. I can't reproduce your other issue with all provided code and example dom

Comment: This worked well... up to a point. After testing on a variety of sites and CMS I found that it was breaking some links, and or, not correcting all links. So I fixed it by performing some chores first, namely dealing with any links that began with "//". I edited to remove the problematic code.